# Discover the IP address of a device on a wired network, MAC not known

Tags: windows, networking, ip, wired-networking

How can I get the IP address of a device (device1) that is connected via ethernet to an unmanaged switch, from another device (device2) connected via ethernet to the same switch?

- Internet access to switch can be disconnected to simplify connected network
- These 2 devices are the only two on the switch (thus in the entire network)
- The MAC address of the device1 is not known
- Device2 runs Windows

Comment: Try Advanced IP Scanner (Famatech)

Comment: You can also use the broadcast address and the arp table. Open cmd, run `arp -d` then `ping 192.168.1.255`. or whatever your network is, making sure .255 is at the end. Then `arp -a` to see a list of the machines in the network.

Comment: Do you have a router that provides a DHCP server for your network? The DHCP server should have a table of MAC addresses and assigned IP addresses. Or do the devices negotiate addresses without a DHCP server?

Comment: Scanning the entire IPv4 space is your only option, but certain parts (private networks) could be prioritized. I cannot write a complete answer for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

`C:\> nmap 192.168.1.0/24` will print info on each host it finds.

Assuming your LAN is 192.168.1.0 with the 24 highest bits defining the net.

*nmap for windows:*
https://www.google.com/search?q=nmap+windows

Comment: Nmap is not installed on Windows by default.

Comment: "default" might have been a been hindrance when internet connections were slow, but today? According to this, https://nmap.org/book/inst-windows.html - it has been around since year 2000

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
arp -a
```

Depending on your subnets it may or may not see it.

Comment: For some reason, this returned a large number of results even on a closed LAN with only these 2 devices connected, and didn't list hostnames so I wasn't able to determine which.